# Change the direction of sorting keys expressions in ClickHouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

Creating a datasource in Tinybird with this schema works as expected

```
DESCRIPTION generated from ../datasets/posts_1K.csv

SCHEMA >
    `date` Date,
    `post_id` Int32,
    `views` Int32

ENGINE MergeTree
ENGINE_SORTING_KEY date, post_id
```

I wonder if I can change the direction of the ordering in one of the expressions of the sorting key. This schema fails

```
DESCRIPTION generated from ../datasets/posts_1K.csv

SCHEMA >
    `date` Date,
    `post_id` Int32,
    `views` Int32

ENGINE MergeTree
ENGINE_SORTING_KEY date DESC, post_id
```

When doing `tb push datasources/posts_1K_sorted_date_desc_post_id.datasource`. Also tried with `ENGINE_SORTING_KEY "date DESC, post_id"`

Is something like this possible at all on ClickHouse or not? Not sure if it's possible reading the [docs](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/create/table/)

Also - would something like this make sense in any case?

Answer (score 1):

> ENGINE_SORTING_KEY date DESC

Is not possible. No plans to implement.
For the most use-cases has no sense.

CH able to use `ENGINE_SORTING_KEY date ASC` for optimization of `select order by date desc`

In rare cases it could improve short exact real-time queries. People use hack `order by -date` or `order by additional_date_substracted_from_max_date` https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/11564#issue-635913235